# Tweaking SNR margin without telnet

Tags: ssh, router, modem, telnet, adsl-router

I need to tweak my router's SNR margin. I know it can be done by telnet but my router's telnet and ssh are disabled. And I cannot find a way to enable telnet ( [How can I enable Telnet on a router](https://superuser.com/questions/369672/how-can-i-enable-telnet-on-a-router) )

So is there a way to tweak router's SNR margin without telnet or ssh?

Btw router is Airties RT-204. But I think this is not important.

Comment: define "tweak" ? You can fix the margin by getting your telco to do it.

Comment: There's a tool which can tweak SNR margin: http://dmt.mhilfe.de/ But it uses Telnet so I cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *general* way to do this if it's not available in the UI and you can't get in via telnet etc. The model does matter, as these things aren't standardised and every one behaves differently.

If you have SNR problems, have you tried the usual (a) complain to telco (b) fiddle with microfilters and disconnect extensions etc?

You've also already posted this at [Tweaking SNR margin without telnet](https://superuser.com/questions/369816/tweaking-snr-margin-without-telnet)