# Tweaking SNR margin

Tags: ssh, router, modem, telnet, adsl-router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tweaking SNR margin without telnet](https://superuser.com/questions/369816/tweaking-snr-margin-without-telnet)

How can I tweak a adsl-router's SNR margin?

I can't access it with telnet or ssh.

This information is not important but router is Airties RT-204